How to make Dash Ag-Grid column wider?
I'm making a table in Python Dash Ag-Grid and I can't seem to make a column wider. I've got lots of extra space to the right, and I thought columnSize=auto-size or columnSize=sizeToFit would make the table fill the entire space.

Here's the column for columnDefs:
        {
            "field": "description",
            "headerName": "Part Description",
            "headerTooltip": "More information about the part",
            "wrapText": True,
            "autoHeight": True,
            "cellDataType": "text",
            "sortable": True,
            "resizable": True,
            "filter": True,
            # note my attempts at setting width params below:
            "minWidth": 100,
            "width": 180,
            "maxWidth": 400,
        },

Here's the AgGrid itself:
AgGrid(
    id="inventory_ag_grid",
    # Default theme is "ag-theme-quartz"
    className="ag-theme-quartz",
    dashGridOptions={
        "skipHeaderOnAutoSize": True,
    },
    # 80vh is 80% of the viewport height
    style={
        "height": "50vh",
        "width": "100%",
    },
    # https://dash.plotly.com/dash-ag-grid/column-sizing
    columnSize="autoSize",
    defaultColDef={"resizable": True},
    getRowStyle={
        "styleConditions": [
            {
                # Set every 2nd row to have a background color
                "condition": "params.rowIndex % 2 === 0",
                "style": {
                    "backgroundColor": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)",
                },
            },
        ]
    },
)

Documentation:
https://dash.plotly.com/dash-ag-grid/column-sizing
Here's a reproducible example:
import pandas as pd
from dash import html, dcc, callback, Input, Output, State
from dash_ag_grid import AgGrid
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import time

rows = [
    {'warehouse_name': 'Stettler', 'part_name': 'part1', 'description': 'Piston Packing and Head O-Rings and lots more text so we can see what it\'s like when the column wraps and we have a really really long description that can\'t fit on one line', 'cost_cad': 5000.0, 'cost_usd': 3521.0, 'msrp_cad': 15001.0, 'msrp_usd': 12008.0, 'warehouse_quantity': 0.1, 'sold_quantity': 0.2, 'calc_quantity': 2.0, 'actual_quantity': None},
{'warehouse_name': 'Stettler', 'part_name': 'part2', 'description': 'Rod Packing, ONE END ONLY', 'cost_cad': 545.0, 'cost_usd': 384.0, 'msrp_cad': 1636.0, 'msrp_usd': 1309.0, 'warehouse_quantity': 0.0, 'sold_quantity': 0.4, 'calc_quantity': 2.0, 'actual_quantity': None},
{'warehouse_name': 'Stettler', 'part_name': 'part3', 'description': 'Hydraulic Piston Seals & O-Rings, ONE END ONLY', 'cost_cad': 272.0, 'cost_usd': 192.0, 'msrp_cad': 816.0, 'msrp_usd': 653.0, 'warehouse_quantity': 1.6, 'sold_quantity': 0.4, 'calc_quantity': 2.0, 'actual_quantity': None}
]
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)

def get_inventory_columns() -> list:
    """Get the columns for the inventory table"""

    price_col = "cost_cad"
    header_name = "Part Cost CAD"

    columns = [
        {
            "field": "warehouse_name",
            "headerName": "Warehouse Name",
            "sortable": True,
            "resizable": True,
            "filter": True,
        },
        {
            "field": "part_name",
            "headerName": "Part Number",
            "cellDataType": "text",
            "wrapText": True,
            "sortable": True,
            "resizable": True,
            "filter": True,
        },
        {
            "field": "description",
            "headerName": "Description NOT Auto-Sized",
            # "headerTooltip": "More information about the part",
            "cellDataType": "text",
            "wrapText": True,
            "autoHeight": True,
            "sortable": True,
            "resizable": True,
            "filter": True,
            "maxWidth": 600,
        },
        {
            "field": price_col,
            "headerName": header_name,
            "sortable": True,
            "resizable": True,
            "filter": True,
        },
        {
            "field": "warehouse_quantity",
            "headerName": "Warehouse Quantity from BoM",
            "sortable": True,
            "resizable": True,
            "filter": True,
        },
        {
            "field": "sold_quantity",
            "headerName": "Sold Quantity",
            "sortable": True,
            "resizable": True,
            "filter": True,
        },
        {
            "field": "calc_quantity",
            "headerName": "Calculated Avg Quantity",
            "sortable": True,
            "resizable": True,
            "filter": True,
        },
        {
            "field": "actual_quantity",
            "headerName": "Actual Quantity",
            "sortable": True,
            "resizable": True,
            "filter": True,
            "editable": True,
        },
    ]

    return columns

# Dash app
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.H1("Ag-Grid Example"),
        dbc.Spinner(
            id="inventory_col",
            color="success",
            children=AgGrid(
                id="inventory_ag_grid",
                className="ag-theme-quartz",
                dashGridOptions={
                    "skipHeaderOnAutoSize": False,
                },
                # 80vh is 80% of the viewport height
                style={
                    "height": "80vh",
                    "width": "100%",
                },
                columnSize="autoSize",
                defaultColDef={"resizable": True},
                getRowStyle={
                    "styleConditions": [
                        {
                            # Set every 2nd row to have a background color
                            "condition": "params.rowIndex % 2 === 0",
                            "style": {
                                "backgroundColor": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)",
                            },
                        },
                    ]
                },
            ),
        ),
    ]
)

@app.callback(
    Output("inventory_ag_grid", "columnDefs"),
    Input("inventory_col", "children"),
)
def update_inventory_columns(children):
    # Wait for auto-sizing to finish
    time.sleep(2)
    return get_inventory_columns()


@app.callback(
    Output("inventory_ag_grid", "rowData"),
    Input("inventory_col", "children"),
)
def update_inventory_rows(children):
    # Wait for auto-sizing to finish
    time.sleep(2)
    return df.to_dict("records")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)



I found the solution.
In production, I'm actually updating the "rowData" and "columnDefs" in a callback. Since they're not available when the "auto-size" is run, it doesn't actually work. The "columnSize" needs to be set after the "rowData" and "columnDefs" are set, in a chained callback.
This works:
    @dash_app.callback(
        Output("inventory_ag_grid", "columnSize"),
        Input("inventory_ag_grid", "columnDefs"),
        prevent_initial_call=True,
    )
    def set_column_size_after_columnDefs_and_rowData(_):
        """Must set the column size after the columnDefs and rowData; otherwise it won't work!"""
        # autoSize fits the column width to its content
        return "autoSize"

I found the solution in this other question:
https://community.plotly.com/t/how-does-columnsize-autosize-work-when-aggrid-dag-values-are-set-with-a-callback/74798
